# strrchr causing 'Cannot convert from const char * to char *'

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile some code that was given to me that I'm told compiles fine.  Perhaps on a different compiler.  I am using VS2010 and I have the following line:

```
char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
```

This causes the compiler error:

> "error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char *' to
>   'char *'

How come?  And how do I fix it?

Comment: I modified the tags, because I didn't see any references to C++ here.

Comment: What is the type of `filename`?

Comment: @Richard: Don't do that.  As Kerrek points out in his answer, the overloads present in the C++ Standard Library will have a significant impact on the behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. `strrchr` returns a `const char*`. So you need:

```
const char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
```

If you really need a `char*`, you can use `strcpy` for conversion.

Comment: or convert results to `char*` like this: `(char*) strrchr(filename), '.');`

Comment: @AtoMerZ: better explicitly use a `const_cast`.

Comment: @AtoMerZ it's never a good idea to cast away const-ness. It could result in undefined behavior.

Comment: In some of the situations I encountered I needed to be able to modify results, that's why I prefer converting result to a non constant type.

Comment: @AtoMerZ I repeat myself - that can lead to undefined behavior. If you need `char*` instead of `const char*`, use `strcpy`.

Comment: @atoMerz If you need to be able to modify the string, you should thus have a char * (not const char*) pointer to the string. If you pass that to strrchr, it will return a char *. (TIL about these overloads...)

Answer (score 5):

C++ has saner versions of `strchr` and `strrchr` than C thanks to overloading, so say:

```
const char * dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
```

In C, which has no overloading, you only have a single function `char * strrchar(const char *, const char *)`, and it's up to you to decide whether the result is constant or mutable, depending on which type of pointer to feed into the function. C has many such type-unsafe functions.